# Custom Keras Layer fails with "TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I reduced my problem to this very basic example:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class MyLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, z):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
        self.z = z

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs * self.z
      
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
layer = MyLayer(inputs)
z = layer(inputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=z)
```

Which fails with

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.math.multiply_17')> with type KerasTensor
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot multiply a `Keras` symbolic tensor with a `Tensorflow` tensor in graph [mode](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs). There are a few ways to do what you want IIUC, here is one option assuming you want to pass two tensors to `MyLayer`:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class MyLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        return x * y
      
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,))
layer = MyLayer()
z = layer([inputs, inputs])

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=z)
```

Comment: Thanks, but where was I using a Keras tensor? Your code seems identical to mine, except that I was storing one tensor in MyLayer's state. What has fundamentally changed? Sorry I'm new to Keras...

Comment: No problem, you were feeding the `Keras` symbolic input to the init method of `MyLayer`. I am referring to `z`. Try printing out the type of `z` and `inputs` in the `call` method and you will see what I mean. Just run `print(type(self.z))` and `print(type(inputs))`